# How to position an element on the Y-Axis based on an Item [SAPUI5]

Tags: hyperlink, position, sapui5, text-align

as the title states, i do have two elements within one `HBox`, a `link` and a `button`, with the problem that i want the link to be displayed in the the same line-height as the middle of the `button`.

Code:

```
<HBox>
    <Link text="Hallo Welt"/>
    <Button 
        icon="sap-icon://warning2" class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin"/>
        
</HBox>
```

**Where the link is right now:**

[image: Link upper Part]

**Where the link should be:**

[image: Red Line]

**Question**: How to position `link` in the middle of `Button`?

Comment: What does the combination of the link and the button semantically represent? You might want to use `sap.m.ObjectStatus` instead which supports a press event and an icon. Or how about a transparent `sap.m.Button` with `iconFirst="false"`? Anyhow, it would be nice if you could add what you're actually trying to achieve in order to avoid common _xy-problems_.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really intuitive but proper samples for `HBox` can be found in `FlexBox`.

See [the sample page](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.FlexBox) for different alignments.

You probably want

```
<HBox alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Start">
```

But as @Boghyon wrote in his comment there might be better approaches if your use case is different.